# ElasticSearch create an index with dynamic properties

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

Is it possible to create an index, restricting indexing a parent property?

For example,

```
$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/actions/action/' -d '{
  "user": "kimchy",
  "message": "trying out Elasticsearch",
  "actionHistory": [
    { "timestamp": 123456789, "action": "foo" },
    { "timestamp": 123456790, "action": "bar" },
    { "timestamp": 123456791, "action": "buz" },
    ...
  ]
}'
```

I don't want `actionHistory` to be indexed *at all*. How can this be done?

For the above document, I believe the index would be created as

```
$ curl -XPOST localhost:9200/actions -d '{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "action": {
      "properties" : {
        "user": { "type": "string", "index" : "analyzed" },
        "message": { "type": "string": "index": "analyzed" },
        "actionHistory": {
          "properties": {
            "timestamp": { 
              "type": "date", 
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
            },
            "action": { "type": "string", "index": "analyzed" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Would removing `properties` from `actionHistory` and replace it with `"index": "no"` be the proper solution?

This is an example, however my actual situation are documents with dynamic properties (i.e. `actionHistory` contains various custom, non-repeating properties across all documents) and my mapping definition for this particular type has over 2000 different properties, making searches extremely slow (i.e. worst than full text search from the database).

Comment: Hm, how are your search queries built that having `actionHistory` so different make them have bad performance? Are you using `_all` in your searches or field names wildcards?

Comment: yes, I let users user the `query_string` form.

Comment: That's the downside of allowing user to do whatever they want with `query_string`. And the same goes with allowing users to create _various custom, non-repeating properties across all documents_. You can have all sorts of issues from these arbitrary query_strings and having whatever properties in your documents. I'd suggest restricting these freedoms for a more stable and predictable cluster.

Comment: Unfortunately, as the sole programmer, and with very limited resources (only 1 single physical server), this restriction is the kind of limitation I have to work with :/

Comment: Right. Then what @Val suggested should be the way forward.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get away by using [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#path-match-unmatch), match on all `actionHistory` sub-fields and set `"index": "no"` for all of them.

```
PUT actions
{
  "mappings": {
    "action": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "actionHistoryRule": {
            "path_match":   "actionHistory.*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "{dynamic_type}",
              "index": "no"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```